# JSPM bundle Angular 2 'sourceType: module' error

Tags: angular, jspm

I am trying to create a JSPM bundle using Angular 2 version 2.2.1.

Using this command:

```
jspm bundle @angular/common + @angular/compiler + @angular/core + @angular/forms + @angular/http + @angular/platform-browser + @angular/platform-browser-dynamic + @angular/router + @angular/upgrade
```

Results in this error:

```
err  SyntaxError: jspm_packages/npm/@angular/core@2.2.1/src/facade/lang.js: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (23:0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Angular2 supports UMD/AMD modules, so JSPM can be set to work like so:

```
"overrides": {
  "npm:@angular/common@2.2.1": {
    "format": "amd"
  },
  "npm:@angular/compiler@2.2.1": {
    "format": "amd"
  },
  "npm:@angular/core@2.2.1": {
    "format": "amd"
  },
  "npm:@angular/forms@2.2.1": {
    "format": "amd"
  },
  "npm:@angular/http@2.2.1": {
    "format": "amd"
  },
  "npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.2.1": {
    "format": "amd"
  },
  "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.2.1": {
    "format": "amd"
  },
  "npm:@angular/upgrade@2.2.1": {
    "format": "amd"
  },
```